# Netlogo / set turtles away from walls

Tags: netlogo

I am a NetLogo newbie.  Am trying to place my turtles using the sexty command in random locations anywhere one patch away from the four walls of grid.  So I assume this involves using `min`/`max pxcor`.  My understanding is the default grid is `-5` to `5` for both the `x` and `y` axes.  I guess I want to define `max-pxcor` and `max-pycor < 5` and `min-pxcor` and `min-pycor > -5`.  Tried various command combinations but keep getting errors.  Am I on the right track?  Perhaps I should take a different approach?

Comment: Show us what you tried and what error message (or other unexpected behavior) you got.